# Getting data from API with AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, api, get

I am trying to get data from API and display them using AJAX
I have this code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
          $('.show').click(function(){     
          $.ajax({
           url: 'url',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {
              var items = [];
              $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');    

              });

              $('<ul/>', {
                 'class': 'interest-list',
                 html: items.join('')
              }).appendTo('body');

           },
          statusCode: {
             404: function() {
               alert('There was a problem with the server.  Try again soon!');
             }
           }
    });
    });
    });
```

I have this result:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
```

What must I fix in my code?

Comment: @Islam Elshobokshy ,it must be added to the body,but it just add [Object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

Comment: code - http://jsfiddle.net/8ut5q62k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.each` iterates over the array, and `key` was the index of the array, and `val` was the entire object

You could change this line of code

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
```

to

```
var key = Object.keys(val)[0];
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val[key] + "</li>");
```

to just get the first key directly.
Here is the documentation for 
[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd better add the `type:'GET'` field to define what kind of call are you doing. 
Then you can use `var json = JSON.parse(data)` to read all the incoming data from `data` like this:

```
var time = json['foo'];
```

or if you have an array:

```
var time = json[index]['foo'];
```

you can find more details here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp and here https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: The default `type` is GET, dataType is set to json so the data is already converted 
 and you don't use `JSON.parse`